# How to write a function using Async and Await techniques?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I want to run a void function that writes to a textblock in WPF

```
private async Task<int> TASK_ClickthroughBuild(string server, int frame, int click)
{
    if (server == "value")
    {
        CreativeCode.Inlines.Add(openScript + newLine);
        CreativeCode.Inlines.Add("var " + click + " = '%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%';" + newLine);
        CreativeCode.Inlines.Add("var " + frame + " = document.getElementById('" + frame + "');" + newLine);
        CreativeCode.Inlines.Add(frame + ".href = " + click + ";" + newLine);
        CreativeCode.Inlines.Add(closeScript);
        PASSBACKframeINT = frame;              
    }
    return PASSBACKframeINT;
}
```

The above function returns an integer value and writes code to a textblock.

This is the second function.

```
private async Task clickElementBuild()
{
    CreativeCode.Inlines.Add("<a href='#' id='" + PASSBACKframeINT + "' target='_blank' class='" + PASSBACKwrapINT + "' >" + newLine);
    CreativeCode.Inlines.Add("<div class='" + PASSBACKblockINT + "' id='" + overlayINT + "'></div>" + newLine);
}
```

The second function, the code needs to write the textblock code ABOVE the first function, but depends on the returned value of first function to write properly.

So I need to write this in an Asynchronous format.  Can I have pointers or a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Your title is bad.

Comment: Why do you need to do this asynchronously? Seems everything is synchronous...

Comment: because of the other function needing the return value to write the correct values to the textblock.  PASSBACKframeINT Is needed by the second function, but the second functions text lines need to be above the text in the first function.

Comment: KaiMHirst Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit and make your title clear as @UweKeim suggested

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you're using .NET 4.5 or else you'd have chosen a Threading-Solution.

Calling an async Function is basically telling the Mainthread to pass everything to a Backgroundthread.

As asynchronous functions are called there's the "risk of soft data consistency". Like in your case or in simpler words the analogy of Forms.show() and Forms.showDialog().

There are several ways to bypass this.
Threading solves this with JOIN() OR WAITALL()
and async with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x) or some prefer Application.DoEvents()

You can place an Await-For-Background-Task-Clause above your Code which
is in risk of "soft data consistency" or place the code it in the Mainthread.

If you're new to async functions. I recommend this tutorial to use it.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/06/01/how-to-simplify-asynchronous-programming.aspx

Comment: Don't use threading. Use Task and async/await whenever you can. Also, async and await does not start a new thread. It is asynchronous, not "parallel"

Comment: Quit the quibbling. I said basically.

Comment: Nope. This is one of the biggest misconceptions of async/await. I don't want the OP to be confused later on.

Comment: Ok. Any references on that ? Where do you have your wisdom from ?

Comment: @EmperorAiman https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20%28v=vs.110%29.aspx    Please prove me different

Answer (score -3):

Sorted. Basically, return the value and used Async to await the returned value in the first place.